Combines 2 SQL Queries that has Union
I have 2 query that return different column output. Query 1 have Union while query 2 is a little bit simple. I try to use union but since the column output is different, It will become error. The full queries is as follows :
---------- QUERY 1
SELECT (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT el.REFERENCE
            FROM T_LEJ el
            WHERE el.REFERENCE <> 'NUM'
                AND el.REFERENCE <> 'J'
                AND el.REFERENCE <> 'DEBIT'
                AND el.REFERENCE <> 'CREDIT'
                AND el.REFERENCE <> 'COMPOUND'
                AND el.REFERENCE <> 'TICKET'
                AND el.REFERENCE <> 'P'
                AND el.REFERENCE NOT LIKE 'BBK%'
        )
    ) AS total,
    CASE
        WHEN c.DOC_TYPE = '1 RECEIPT' THEN 'RECEIPT'
        ELSE c.DOC_TYPE
    END AS DOC_TYPE,
    c.ACC_NUM,
    NVL(c.CKAI, 0) AS CKAI,
    NVL(c.COMPOUND, 0) AS COMPOUND,
    NVL(c.TICKET, 0) AS TICKET,
    NVL(c.P, 0) AS P
    
FROM (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM (
        SELECT
            '1 RECEIPT' AS DOC_TYPE,
            COUNT(DISTINCT el.ACC_NUM) AS ACC_NUM,
            SUM(CASE WHEN el.REF_CODE = '61101' THEN NVL(SUM(el.CREDIT - el.DEBIT), 0) END) AS CKAI,
            SUM(CASE WHEN el.REF_CODE = '76101' THEN NVL(SUM(el.CREDIT - el.DEBIT), 0) END) AS COMPOUND,
            SUM(CASE WHEN el.REF_CODE = '76102' THEN NVL(SUM(CREDIT - DEBIT), 0) END) AS TICKET,
            SUM(CASE WHEN el.REF_CODE = '76103' THEN NVL(SUM(CREDIT - DEBIT), 0) END) AS P
        FROM T_LEJ el
        WHERE el.REFERENCE = 'RECEIPT'
        AND el.TRK_TRANS BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/2024', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('31/01/2024', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
        GROUP BY el.REF_CODE, el.CREDIT, el.DEBIT, el.ACC_NUM
    ) A
    UNION
    SELECT
        *
    FROM (
        SELECT
            SUBSTR(CONCAT(ra.SF, CONCAT(' | ', ra.DETAIL)), 0, 35) AS DOC_TYPE,
            COUNT(DISTINCT lej.SELECT
    DOC_TYPE,
    SUM(e.BIL_KLMPK) AS total_bil_klmpk
FROM (
    SELECT
        DISTINCT e.NO_KELOMPOK,
        SUBSTR(CONCAT(ra.SF, CONCAT(' | ', ra.KETERANGAN)), 0, 35) AS DOC_TYPE,
        e.BIL_KLMPK
    FROM
        ETTRANS e
    LEFT JOIN
        ETTRANS_DET ed ON e.NO_KELOMPOK = ed.NO_KELOMPOK
    LEFT JOIN
        T_LEJ el ON ed.ACC_NUM = el.ACC_NUM
    LEFT JOIN
        REF_AGENCY ra ON el.REFERENCE = ra.SF
    WHERE
        e.COLL_CENTER = ra.SF
        AND 
        e.TRK_KLMPK >= TO_DATE('2024-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
        AND e.TRK_KLMPK <= TO_DATE('2024-01-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
) e
GROUP BY
    DOC_TYPE
ORDER BY 
    DOC_TYPE;
) AS ACC_NUM,
            NVL(SUM(lej.CKAI), 0) AS CKAI,
            NVL(SUM(lej.COMPOUND), 0) AS COMPOUND,
            NVL(SUM(lej.TICKET), 0) AS TICKET,
            NVL(SUM(lej.P), 0) AS P
        FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT el.REFERENCE
            FROM T_LEJ el
            WHERE el.REFERENCE <> 'NUM'
                AND el.REFERENCE <> 'J'
                AND el.REFERENCE <> 'DEBIT'
                AND el.REFERENCE <> 'CREDIT'
                AND el.REFERENCE <> 'COMPOUND'
                AND el.REFERENCE <> 'TICKET'
                AND el.REFERENCE <> 'P'
                AND el.REFERENCE <> 'RECEIPT'
                AND el.REFERENCE NOT LIKE 'BBK%'
        ) ruj
        LEFT JOIN REF_AGENCY ra ON ruj.REFERENCE = ra.SF
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
                el.REFERENCE,
                el.ACC_NUM,
                CASE
                    WHEN el.REF_CODE = '61101' THEN NVL(SUM(CREDIT - DEBIT), 0)
                END AS CKAI,
                CASE
                    WHEN el.REF_CODE = '76101' THEN NVL(SUM(CREDIT - DEBIT), 0)
                END AS COMPOUND,
                CASE
                    WHEN el.REF_CODE = '76102' THEN NVL(SUM(CREDIT - DEBIT), 0)
                END AS TICKET,
                CASE
                    WHEN el.REF_CODE = '76103' THEN NVL(SUM(CREDIT - DEBIT), 0)
                END AS P
            FROM REF_AGENCY ra
            LEFT JOIN T_LEJ el ON ra.SF = el.REFERENCE
            WHERE el.TRK_TRANS BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/2024', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('31/01/2024', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
            GROUP BY el.REFERENCE, el.CREDIT, el.DEBIT, el.REF_CODE, el.ACC_NUM
        ) lej ON ra.SF = lej.REFERENCE
        GROUP BY ra.SF, ra.DETAIL
    ) B
) C
ORDER BY c.DOC_TYPE;

The output of Query 1:

---- QUERY 2
SELECT
    DOC_TYPE,
    SUM(e.NUM_GROUP) AS TOTAL_NUM_GROUP
FROM (
    SELECT
        DISTINCT e.GROUP_ID,
        SUBSTR(CONCAT(ra.SF, CONCAT(' | ', ra.REFERENCE)), 0, 35) AS DOC_TYPE,
        e.NUM_GROUP
    FROM
        T_TRANSACTION e
    LEFT JOIN
        T_TRANSACTION_DET ed ON e.GROUP_ID = ed.GROUP_ID
    LEFT JOIN
        T_LEJ el ON ed.ACC_NUM = el.ACC_NUM
    LEFT JOIN
        REF_AGENCY ra ON el.REFERENCE = ra.SF
    WHERE
        e.COLL_CENTER = ra.SF
        AND 
        e.TRK_KLMPK >= TO_DATE('2024-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
        AND e.TRK_KLMPK <= TO_DATE('2024-01-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
) e
GROUP BY
    DOC_TYPE
ORDER BY 
    DOC_TYPE;

The output of Query 2:

I want to combine both query in one query (Query 2 to Query 1). The expected output should look like the following
Expected Output  (The highlight supposedly from query 2 ):


Looking at the expected result is what you want just a plain old join of queries 1 nad 2 over doc_type (something like SELECT * FROM q1 FULL OUTER JOIN q2 ON q1.DOC_TYPE = q2.DOC_TYPE) or is there something more to it that I'm missing?

Which dbms are you using? (Several product specific functions used.)

Make it easy to assist you - simplify! And a prepared fiddle would probably speed things up. (E.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/ can be used.)

, I use Oracle SQL

SELECT (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT el.REFERENCE
            FROM T_LEJ el
            WHERE el.REFERENCE <> 'NUM'
                AND el.REFERENCE <> 'J'
                AND el.REFERENCE <> 'DEBIT'
                AND el.REFERENCE <> 'CREDIT'
                AND el.REFERENCE <> 'COMPOUND'
                AND el.REFERENCE <> 'TICKET'
                AND el.REFERENCE <> 'P'
                AND el.REFERENCE NOT LIKE 'BBK%'
        )
    ) AS total,
    CASE
        WHEN c.DOC_TYPE = '1 RECEIPT' THEN 'RECEIPT'
        ELSE c.DOC_TYPE
    END AS DOC_TYPE,
    c.ACC_NUM,
    NVL(c.CKAI, 0) AS CKAI,
    NVL(c.COMPOUND, 0) AS COMPOUND,
    NVL(c.TICKET, 0) AS TICKET,
    NVL(c.P, 0) AS P
FROM (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM (
        SELECT
            '1 RECEIPT' AS DOC_TYPE,
            COUNT(DISTINCT el.ACC_NUM) AS ACC_NUM,
            SUM(CASE WHEN el.REF_CODE = '61101' THEN NVL(SUM(el.CREDIT - el.DEBIT), 0) END) AS CKAI,
            SUM(CASE WHEN el.REF_CODE = '76101' THEN NVL(SUM(el.CREDIT - el.DEBIT), 0) END) AS COMPOUND,
            SUM(CASE WHEN el.REF_CODE = '76102' THEN NVL(SUM(CREDIT - DEBIT), 0) END) AS TICKET,
            SUM(CASE WHEN el.REF_CODE = '76103' THEN NVL(SUM(CREDIT - DEBIT), 0) END) AS P
        FROM T_LEJ el
        WHERE el.REFERENCE = 'RECEIPT'
        AND el.TRK_TRANS BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/2024', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('31/01/2024', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
        GROUP BY el.REF_CODE, el.CREDIT, el.DEBIT, el.ACC_NUM
    ) A
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        *
    FROM (
        SELECT
            SUBSTR(CONCAT(ra.SF, CONCAT(' | ', ra.DETAIL)), 0, 35) AS DOC_TYPE,
            COUNT(DISTINCT lej.DOC_TYPE) AS ACC_NUM,
            NVL(SUM(lej.CKAI), 0) AS CKAI,
            NVL(SUM(lej.COMPOUND), 0) AS COMPOUND,
            NVL(SUM(lej.TICKET), 0) AS TICKET,
            NVL(SUM(lej.P), 0) AS P
        FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT el.REFERENCE AS DOC_TYPE
            FROM T_LEJ el
            WHERE el.REFERENCE <> 'NUM'
                AND el.REFERENCE <> 'J'
                AND el.REFERENCE <> 'DEBIT'
                AND el.REFERENCE <> 'CREDIT'
                AND el.REFERENCE <> 'COMPOUND'
                AND el.REFERENCE <> 'TICKET'
                AND el.REFERENCE <> 'P'
                AND el.REFERENCE <> 'RECEIPT'
                AND el.REFERENCE NOT LIKE 'BBK%'
        ) ruj
        LEFT JOIN REF_AGENCY ra ON ruj.DOC_TYPE = ra.SF
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
                el.REFERENCE AS DOC_TYPE,
                el.ACC_NUM,
                CASE
                    WHEN el.REF_CODE = '61101' THEN NVL(SUM(CREDIT - DEBIT), 0)
                END AS CKAI,
                CASE
                    WHEN el.REF_CODE = '76101' THEN NVL(SUM(CREDIT - DEBIT), 0)
                END AS COMPOUND,
                CASE
                    WHEN el.REF_CODE = '76102' THEN NVL(SUM(CREDIT - DEBIT), 0)
                END AS TICKET,
                CASE
                    WHEN el.REF_CODE = '76103' THEN NVL(SUM(CREDIT - DEBIT), 0)
                END AS P
            FROM REF_AGENCY ra
            LEFT JOIN T_LEJ el ON ra.SF = el.REFERENCE
            WHERE el.TRK_TRANS BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/2024', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('31/01/2024', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
            GROUP BY el.REFERENCE, el.CREDIT, el.DEBIT, el.REF_CODE, el.ACC_NUM
        ) lej ON ra.SF = lej.DOC_TYPE
        GROUP BY ra.SF, ra.DETAIL
    ) B
) C
ORDER BY c.DOC_TYPE;
Let me know if this is what you are looking for.


Thanks but No. That Not I am looking for.
I want to get TOTAL_NUM_GROUP ( from query 2) to be together in query 1. As I highlight

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
